# Printing output from loop in R markdown

Tags: loops, r-markdown, output, regression, capture

I want to print the output from loop procedure using library(olsrr), and specifically the output of summary(model). The code is

```
library(olsrr)
for (i in 10:13) {
  model_components<-lm(data=pheno2,pheno2[[i]]~breed + parity + dim_clas + dmy + sample)
  both.p_components<-ols_step_both_p(model_components, penter=0.05, prem=0.1)
  print(names(pheno2)[i])
  print(both.p_components)
```

However, after conversion to html or pdf with knitr, it is displayed without spacing between the parameters and the estimates look like this for each feature:

```
0.1 Stepwise Selection Summary

                 Added/                   Adj.                                        

0.2 Step Variable Removed R-Square R-Square C(p) AIC RMSE

1 dim_clas addition0.2650.26449.15902239.67240.9943
2 dmyaddition0.2850.28328.46102206.05970.9814
3 parityaddition0.3080.3054.27702182.18180.9660
```

i tried to modify the code using

```
for (i in 10:13) {
  model_components<-lm(data=pheno2,pheno2[[i]]~breed + parity + dim_clas + dmy + sample)
  both.p_components<-ols_step_both_p(model_components, penter=0.05, prem=0.1)
  print(names(pheno2)[i])
  print(both.p_components) %>% 
    kbl(caption= "blal", alig="lccrr") %>% 
    kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font= "Cambria")
  out<- capture.output(both.p_components)
```

}

but, unfortunately, don't work. The output is the same!!! Any idea?

Comment: Could you put together a minimal example that we can run?